# <ToggleButton> onClickListener - Create/Delete button + add content to button

Tags: android, button, togglebutton

I have this problem with my ToggleButton.
I want it to create/delete a button upon being toggled, and at the same time add content/functions to the button, like drawable and such.

This is the current code:

```
            public class BillardScoreboardActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button minuskegle, minuskugle, pluskugle, pluskegle, plusmidkegle, minusmidkegle, miss;
ToggleButton toggle;
LinearLayout bottomlayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.bRedGreen);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pluskugle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBallhole);
            minuskugle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBallhole);

            pluskegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKegle);
            minuskegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKegle);

            plusmidkegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKeglemid);
            minusmidkegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKeglemid);

            bottomlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomlayout);

            miss = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMiss);

        if(toggle.isChecked())
        {
            minuskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redballinhole);
            minuskegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redkegle);
            minusmidkegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.midkegleminus);
            miss.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.missbutton);

            miss.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        else 
        {
            pluskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whiteballinhole);
            pluskegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kegleb);
            plusmidkegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.midkegleplus);
            miss.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        }

    });
}
```

The current problem is that it can't find the (buttontest) in this part of the code:

```
            else 
        {
            pluskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whiteballinhole);
            pluskegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kegleb);
            plusmidkegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.midkegleplus);
            bottomlayout.removeView(buttontest);

        }
```

And as mentioned earlier, the second problem is to make the button inherit some functions/content.

[image]
for bigger version: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJFVD.png**

Btw... Everytime i start up the application, it gives me 2 apps to choose between, whereof only the bottom one works:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that the togglebutton's initial state is 'checked'. That means when you click it the first time, isChecked() will return false and the else-part of your code will be executed. But at that point, buttontest hasn't been added to bottomlayout yet.

I recommend you to have the button inside the layout by default and call buttontest.setVisibility(View.GONE) when you would like to hide it and buttontest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) when it needs to be shown.
As for your second question, just call setBackgroundResource/Drawable to add content (like you're already doing it with the other buttons). If you say you want to add functionality, I assume you intend to do something when the button is clicked? If yes, add a View.OnClickListener.
Hope I could help you.

Comment: When trying with the setVisibillity it comes up with an unexpected error upon toggling, despite it's not showing any errors in the coding anywhere.

Also i'm a little worried that just hiding the button will make the layout look strange due to the fact that my buttons are in a LinearLayout and their position is defined by: Layout_weight="1.0"

Comment: Could you please post the exception you get? I don't see any reason for this method not to work. It also should have the same result as adding/removing the button to/from the layout, as View.GONE doesn't simply make the button transparent (unlike View.INVISIBLE) but will prevent it from getting layouted, i.e. it won't take any space in the layout.

Comment: I answered this topic, in order to post screenshots

Comment: You should rather edit your question instead. What are you doing in line 52? I would look into the list of installed applications whether you have two entries for your app. You can also try to uninstall and then reinstall it.

Comment: miss.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.missbutton);
is the contents of line 52, i deleted it, but the problem still persists. Also, i can't find the list of installed applications, unless you mean the list of folders with my applications which by default is located to the left (in which there is only 1 app named this).

Comment: Where do you initialize the button called 'miss'? You're at least not doing this in the code you've posted above.
You should be able to find a list of your installed applications somewhere under "settings".

Comment: I defined in the top of the .java file by saying
Button miss;

But yea, i dont see any miss = (Button) findview....... in my code, maybe that's the problem?

It's getting the drawable for the missbutton from an .xml file designed for the purpose.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem, you have to initialize it like you suggested.

Comment: Most of it seems to work now, except this:.............................................................................................        
1. time i toggle = button dissapears.................................                                    
2. time i toggle = button doesn't reappear.......................................................................................................                                   
3. time i toggle = Error message for line:                                          buttontest.setVisibillity(View.VISISBLE)

Comment: Ehm... Could you update your question with your current code as well as the new exception? BTW, you can copy the LogCat stuff, you don't need to make a screenshot.

Comment: I fixed it myself now. The last problem which occured, is that i need the button to be GONE initially, which it isn't i need to toggle twice for the button to be gone from the initial screen.---OBS--- Question updated